# Phoenix/Elixir: tips when to create a new Context

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've started a number of [Phoenix](https://www.phoenixframework.org/) projects, but I always find it challenging to properly define [Contexts](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html). I've often ended up creating "sub-Contexts" within Contexts, which I think is fine, but it's never perfect.

My question is **what tips do people have for defining Phoenix Contexts?** or some sort of litmus test for where to draw lines between Contexts.

---

As an example:

I have an [app](https://slack.whentochat.co/) that integrates with Slack's API, and uses Google's Map API to look up timezone/location information, and uses Stripe for payments.

1. I started with a Slack Context, but quickly found that I was mixing Slack API logic with my app's actual business logic.
2. I put all Google Maps stuff under a Google Context
3. I put all Stripe stuff under a Payments Context

At this point I'm basically separating context by the third-party tool, but ended up with an overly bloated Slack Context. It's also challenging to reframe one's perspective and redefine Contexts once an app has already been established.

Answer (score 7):

#### Quick links for reference

1. [BoundedContext by Martin Fowler (bliki)](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html)
2. [Domain Driven Design Distilled by Vaughn Vernon (book)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134434420)
3. [Designing Elixir Systems With OTP by James Edward Gray, II and Bruce Tate (book)](https://pragprog.com/book/jgotp/designing-elixir-systems-with-otp)

#### Preface

I'll start off by saying that I don't like that we are calling the notion of grouping modules that deal with the same domain problems "Phoenix contexts" because Phoenix is a web framework and these contexts are dealing with the business logic (aka. core functions) of your application.
That said, I am glad that they (Phoenix) are spreading the word about better, more scalable software architecture.

#### What are contexts

The way Phoenix docs describe them is *"Contexts are dedicated modules that expose and group related functionality"*.
This describes contexts from a code point of view, but it doesn't describe contexts conceptually. To get a clearer picture of what a (bounded) context is, I suggest checking out [BoundedContext by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). In short, **they are a way to design and architecture your software so that modules that deal with a specific domain or part of a domain remain encapsulated within a bubble, where they speak their own language which everyone dealing with this problem is familiar with**.

#### Your problem

You mentioned that you created a Slack context, but you ended up mixing the Slack API logic with your business logic.

You are not alone in being confused by this. I am working with a company where I am part of the hiring pipeline. Basically I assess the task assignments submitted by candidates applying for a job and this is one of the most common designs that I encounter.

The problem is that you are thinking about contexts solely in one dimension. You are solely thinking of how to group modules by their similarity in a domain - I like to think of this as "horizontal" grouping.

The trick is to also group modules by their similarity in terms of your application itself aka. which layer of the application the code is dealing with.

#### What are layers

Layers are a way to group modules that are similar in what tasks they are doing in terms of your application architecture. For instance, you can have "business logic" (core, immutable functions) layer, a layer of modules that are dealing with external services (HTTP requests, Slack libraries, Dropbox libraries, ...), a layer of modules that are dealing with application state and lifecycle (GenServers, Supervisors, ...), a layer of modules that are dealing with worker processes and routines (workers modules, ...) etc.

A great resource on layers and how to structure your application that these layers connect to each other as best as possible is [Designing Elixir Systems With OTP by James Edward Gray, II and Bruce Tate](https://pragprog.com/book/jgotp/designing-elixir-systems-with-otp).

This type of grouping is more "vertical" aka. grouping by layers.

You know you have some logic that deals with Slack, so you create a Slack context. You know you have some Google logic, so you create a Google context. Then you also have your main business logic, so you create a Timezones (for example) context.

Notice the difference between the three contexts - Timezones is pretty much a business logic context. We know that some fancy date-time calculations are happening there and that's it. But with Slack and Google it gets more tricky. There might be HTTP requests, some vendor specific error handling, mapping, filtering, reducing etc.

#### How to combine contexts and layers

It's a difficult question to answer this for you because in order to create good contexts I would have to be a domain expert in datetime manipulation, where we search for optimal meeting times (according to your app, [When to chat](https://slack.whentochat.co)). Similarily, to be able to create appropriate modules in appropriate layers I would have to know a bit more what your application is doing from a technical point of view.

I will try, however, to guess what it COULD be doing, just so I can give you an example.

**The layers**

1. I think the first and most important layer is of course your *business logic* layer.
   This is where your secret sauce is. Your magic date manipulation where you calculate the best meeting times. Your modules for this layer can exist in `lib/when_to_chat/`
2. The second layer we will need is the web layer. I am assuming your application exploses some sort of a REST API for other services to call. This is where Phoenix lives basically. The controllers, views, templates, channels etc.; this layer can be at `lib/when_to_chat_web/` (as per Phoenix convention)
3. The third layer we need is the `services` layer. This is where your Slack, Stripe, Google maps integrations are. Here you are making HTTP requests, using libraries that call external services, handling timeouts etc.; the modules for this layer can reside in `lib/when_to_chat_services/` for example
4. Another layer you might need is the database/storage layer. If you are using Ecto and you are persisting some data, all the queries and schemas, validations etc. should reside in this specific layer. The directory for this layer could be `lib/when_to_chat_storage/`

This is just from the top of my head when I was thinking about what your code *might* be doing. Maybe you need another layer to deal with GenServers and Supervisors and such.

**The contexts**

Now for the contexts. Remember that contexts group your modules by *what* they do, and layers group them by *how* they do it.
This also means that you might have different contexts in different layers. For instance, if you think about it, `Slack` is a service that we are integrating. It makes sense to have a Slack context in the service layer, but not in the business logic layer.

So first off, in the business logic layer you could have 3 contexts:
 - timezones <- this is your core magic (example function: `find_best_time_for_users(user)`)
 - payments <- this is where you calculate invoices, discounts etc. (example function: `process_payment(user, amount, selected_provider)`
 - notifications <- this is where you push messages or raise alerts etc. (example function `notify_via_slack(user, notification)`

Next, in the web layer, you have the standard Phoenix stuff, which we will skip here.

After that, in the services layer, you might have the 3 contexts: slack, stripe and google_maps. Inside of them, you deal with some data importing/exporting, but not any core calculation logic.

Finally, in the storage layer, you could have an `accounts` context for storing user info and a `payments` context for dealing with payment queries, tables, schemas, etc..

#### So how does it all look?

Your project might end up looking something like this:
[image: Screenshot of how a project with all the layers and contexts might look like]

Of course this is as much art as it is science. The lines are not super clear and sometimes layers do leak a bit from one to another. The good thing is that with years of experience we learn and improve so refactors are always making our code better!

For even more info on how to design your applications so that they focus on business I suggest checking out [Domain Driven Design Distilled by Vaughn Vernon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134434420).

Final note: my answer is not some sort of standardized way of dealing with software architecture. It's a mix of teachings from the linked references and my own ideas. Feel free to experiment and figure out what works for you and your team!

Answer (score 1):

I was bothered by the term "contexts" when Phoenix first introduced them, maybe because it's a word that can have many different shades of meanings and none of them lined up with architectural terms I had been familiar with in other languages/frameworks.

My take on Phoenix contexts is that they are simply an abstraction (like the "[indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection)" famously described by David Wheeler). If we prioritize the single responsibility principle and therefore aim for thin controllers, and our schema modules are dedicated to defining the representation of the underlying data layer, then for many use cases, we will discover the need an abstraction layer between the two (where we can put in business logic etc).

In other languages/frameworks, I've heard these types of modules/classes described as "service classes", and that definition is equally vague and non-specific. However, no matter what you call them, they fulfill the same need of abstracting logic away from classes/modules that are dedicated to some other purpose.

In your case, you are discovering how to sensibly separate functionality into groups. That sounds like good progress (and there may never be a nice and formulaic way to do it perfectly).  It's natural to discover in the process that one bucket (or "context") may be too large to offer meaningful separation of concerns.  In time, you'll get better at recognizing where to draw those lines, but it's a good skill to cultivate an awareness of when a module is getting too big for its britches -- you smell it.

I find that getting really polished and elegant tests is a good re-enforcement for telling whether or not I made good organizational choices in my abstraction layers.  If I lumped too many things together in one function or module, the tests for it become frustratingly complex and brittle, and that can be a sign that I should refactor my code.

For Phoenix projects, I tend to use the default context for a controller/schema as the thing that pulls together the other related services/modules -- that way each related module can be dedicated to a single responsibility and the context module itself is dedicated to the task of chaining them together.

Hope that helps.